# Unable to uncheck a checkbox within a combo box

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

I have a combo box which contains two List Items. Each list item consists of a checkbox and a text message.
Now, I am using a function which looks something like this to uncheck all the checkbox's within the combobox.

```
public ApplicationReports UnSelectAllCheckBox()
{
    int i = 0;
    ComboBox someVariable= Application.Library.GetFromWindow(Application.Configuration.LoginWindow.Title).OfType<ComboBox>("corresponding Automation Id");

    foreach (ListItem casino in someVariable.Items)                     
    {
        someVariable.Item(i).UnCheck();
        i++;
    }
    // someVariable.Item(0).UnCheck();
    return this;
}
```

I am able to uncheck the second checkbox using this approach but not the first one. Unable to identify
what is the problem when it is working fine for the second list item. I am using the recently released version of
white framework. "someVariable" is not a problem. I checked its retrieving the correct combo box while
debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
foreach (ListItem casino in someVariable.Items)                     
{
    casino.UnCheck();
}
```

No need to use i and make your own loop iterator.

Comment: Sorry, that's my only guess. Leaving the answer here so that others can see this was already suggested.

Comment: I dont understand the fact that when I am able to uncheck the second checkbox within the combo box then why not the first one?

Comment: Its showing WPF Element is OffScreen error when I use casino.Uncheck()

Comment: Check whether the element is off screen first then before calling the `Uncheck` method. For whatever reason, it looks like your item has a child that is offscreen.

Comment: if (!casino.IsOffscreen) { casino.UnCheck(); }

Comment: I have no idea, but the condtion if(!casino.IsOffscreen) is failing for the first item but not for second one.

Comment: This offscreen error has been a great headache for me for a very long time now. I have encountered this so many times with some other controls also. I always have to found a way around this.